# how to do this box with css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm not a pro with CSS and Bootstrap as you will see with my coding. I need to do this with CSS/Bootstrap but I couldn't. I don't know what should I do. can anyone help me?
trying to do this:
[image]

I have come this far

had done this:
[image]

and the code i wrote

HTML

```
<div class="what">
        <div class="icerik">
            <h2>What is Londonist Investments?</h2>
            <div>
                <img src="/assets/slider/bg1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="about float-right">
                <div style="padding: 25px">
                    deneme
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.what{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    margin: 20px 0 50px 0;

}

.what h2{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.icerik{
    padding: 25px;
}

.what img{
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.about{
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #F4FF77;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Also I should mention that, all of this HTML code inside a 'container' class of Bootstrap 4. how can I write this code? these red-quarter circles are another bilg prooblem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need such a result?

```js
let what = document.querySelector('.what');
what.style.height = 'calc(' + what.offsetHeight + 'px + 75px)';
```

```css
.what{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    margin: 20px 0 50px 0;
}

.what h2{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.icerik{
    padding: 25px;
}

.icerik_img {    
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.what img{
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.about{
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F4FF77;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(50%, 25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="what">
        <div class="icerik">
            <h2>What is Londonist Investments?</h2>
            <div class="icerik_img">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNWxHxrSxNwX4gUVIQiAtyOv1Yl41zXYBPPQ&usqp=CAU" alt="">
                
                <div class="about float-right">
                <div style="padding: 25px">
                    deneme
                </div>
            </div>
                
            </div>         
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but I need them all in the dark-grey box. I copied your codes but couldn't get in right position

Comment: @jigsaw075, you mean the indoor blocks must be inside the dark block?

Comment: @jigsaw075, ok. Now I will finish my main work, and redo this it solution.

Comment: check please. I gave the code for js, where the dynamic height of the gray block is calculated and the missing height is added

Comment: thank you. that suits well. sorry for delay